# Mysql Georgian Unicode

Tags: mysql, unicode

I'm having a small issue, I am storing Georgian Unicode text into my database, and it appears in phpmyadmin as:

> áƒœáƒáƒ’áƒ•áƒ˜áƒ¡ áƒ£áƒ áƒœáƒ?

Character set for the database is utf8_general_ci. When I retrieve the text in my php script it appears correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this at the start of your code:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

It will tell PHP to use Unicode to communicate with the database engine.

Comment: I'm not having the issue in my script, it communicates with database correctly and converts the characters correctly, the database itself stores them incorrectly.

Comment: What do you use to view your database? PHPMyAdmin? Command line? The problem could come from there too.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin typically gets charset right, so technically I think you *are* storing `áƒœáƒáƒ’áƒ•áƒ˜áƒ¡ áƒ£áƒ áƒœáƒ` in the database, but then implicitly ‘converting’ that through an accidental latin1<>utf8 process when you don't call `mysql_set_charset`. You should set the charset as in this answer, but also fix the data in your database to match. If you don't then some features that rely on the charset being accurate will fail (most obviously case-insensitive comparisons with non-ASCII).